# Multiply statements run at one time in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin

In postgresql, if multiply SQL statements are executed at one time (In pgadmin, select all these statements and click "execute" button, like this picture), 
[image]

the server will wait until   the last statement is done before the previous statements to take effect. 
When these statements are being executed, if I run `SELECT * FROM tablename1` then the "relation not exist" error will occur.

Are there any ways for the statements to take effect once they are executed.
Note: Every CREATE statement needs very short time if it is executed by itself. The SELECT statement needs a long time.

Comment: «If the last SELECT statement needs a long time to run, the previous CREATE operations will not successfully create tables.» — do you have any evidence for this? And what you mean by «at one time _and_ sequentially» — it is either in parallel or in order, as I see it.

Comment: @vyegorov I updated my question, sorry for the ambiguous.

Answer (score 3):

I assume, that when you select a bunch of statements in pgadmin and hit “Execute”, they all run in a single [transaction](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tutorial-transactions.html). This means, that the results of the transaction will not be visible to the other concurrent sessions till it commits (or not visible at all if transaction fails).

Try adding explicit `COMMIT;` after each `CREATE TABLE` or after the last one.

You may also want to read about [transaction isolation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/transaction-iso.html).